# git rebase cannot 'squash' without a previous commit

Tags: git

I used to use `git rebase -i` all the time, but suddenly it stopped working.

`git rebase` does not work in any project I have, which is weird and I suspect it's something wrong with my git configuration(?)

I've createad a `test` repository to show what I'm doing.

In the test repository I have 2 commits

**$ git log**

```
commit 8fb921a9a481ef1040ee670af7894bff6055a5b4 (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Author: Bu Kinoshita
Date:   Fri May 25 11:26:05 2018 -0300

test 2

commit 00ffa75caccf0118b9e89bc2bb70c4a7417b223a
Author: Bu Kinoshita
Date:   Fri May 25 11:25:39 2018 -0300

test
```

And then `git rebased` with commit hash from the first commit

**git rebase -i 00ffa75caccf0118b9e89bc2bb70c4a7417b223a**

```
pick 8fb921a test 2

# Rebase 00ffa75..8fb921a onto 00ffa75 (1 command)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# d, drop = remove commit
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

Change the first line to `squash 8fb921a test 2` and save the file.

**The error shows up**

```
error: cannot 'squash' without a previous commit
You can fix this with 'git rebase --edit-todo' and then run 'git rebase --continue'.
Or you can abort the rebase with 'git rebase --abort'.
```

Comment: So what happens when you DO have a previous commit like a `test3` commit?

Comment: I get the same error result.

Comment: **torek** has provided an excellent answer to the question as it stands. But I suspect this is not the same problem as you are trying to solve in real life.

Answer (score 4):

> In the test repository I have 2 commits

To squash the second commit into the first one using `git rebase`, you must rebase *both* commits.

Since there are only the two, `git rebase -i` alone won't work.  Using `git rebase -i --root` will.

However, since there *are* only the two commits, and the commit you want to squash is the *current* commit, you can do this without using `git rebase` at all:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git commit --amend
```

The drawback here is that `--amend` will only present the first commit's message for editing; the second commit's message will be gone at this point.  Note that `--amend` doesn't actually *change* the existing commit; instead, it makes a *new* commit whose parents are the current commit's parents.  In this case, the current commit is the root commit, so this uses the root commit's lack-of-parents to make a new root commit.

Comment: The `test` repository was just to represent my problem, I have many other projects with more than 2 commits (real project in production with a lot of commits), git rebase does not work at all in these cases as well.

I tested the `git reset` and `git commit --amend` as you suggest on the test repo, it works. But it's not the solution for my problem because I'm not rebasing my repository.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to post a different question, then, because the one you asked is about using rebase in a two-commit repository.

Comment: In my question I said that "git rebase does not work in any project I have, which is weird and I suspect it's something wrong with my git configuration(?)" And used a test repository as an example only.

Thanks though!

Comment: See [mcve] for a description of providing others enough information to help.

Answer (score 1):

your just squashing in the wrong direction.  squash upwards instead of downwards ..so if you had:

```
Pick ####
Pick ###
Pick ###
```

then squash into one commit this way:

```
Pick ###
Squash ###
Squash ###
```

this way there is a commit before . you can use the reword instead of pick if you need to rename the commit. but a screen will come after you save were you can edit the commit message that the PR review will see

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify a number of commits n, you indicate that with head~n.
Example:   git rebase -i head~2